# How to export values in a self-defined function to predefined dataframe in r

Tags: r, function

I am running a self-defined `function` and I want to extract some values from the function to a predefined `dataframe`. This function will be applied to a list. Each element of the list should make one row of the predefined `dataframe`.
Please see the code below.

I predefined a `dataframe` with four variable ahead of the `function`

```
df <- data.frame(Year = as.integer(),
                 Total_sites = as.integer(),
                 Sites_25 = as.integer(),
                 Missing_hours = as.double())
```

Below is part of the function.

```
fun <- function(a_csv, the_dir) {

  hcount <- dfAOT40 %>% group_by(IDS) %>% 
    summarise(count = n()) 

  hcount_less <- hcount %>% filter(count < 897)

  year <- substring(dfoz$'Date Local'[1], 1, 4)  # first variable in the dataframe

  total_sites <- length(unique(hcount$IDS)) # second variable variable in the dataframe

  sites_25 <- length(unique(hcount_less$IDS)) # third variable in the dataframe

  missing <- sum(hcount$count) / (total_sites * 1196)  # fourth variable in the dataframe

  df <- data.frame(Year = as.integer(),
                   Total_sites = as.integer(),
                   Sites_25 = as.integer(),
                   Missing_hours = as.double())

  df[1,] <-  c(year, total_sites, sites_25, missing) # each element should make one row of the dataframe.

  return(df)

}
```

The problem was solved by the code below.

`df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(files, FUN = fun, the_dir))`

Comment: (1) What you're suggesting is fully *side-effect*, which is really bad practice, breaks reproducible research, and is a real pain to troubleshoot. I urge you to think of things in a more *functional paradigm*. (2) I hesitate to say this (because it goes against point 1), but what you're asking for is either `<<-` or `assign`. Again, really, ignore point 2, read and heed point 1.

Comment: @r2evans I cannot fully understand your point 1. Why you called it 'side-effect'? Did you mean what I wanted is not functions normally do? Or you meant the code was incomplete to troubleshoot. Anyway, problem was solved. Please see the updated post.